# Question about Tomcat for Java Server Based on sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, serversocket, java-server

I would like to know if I purchase a VPS service(linux based) over the net.
Do I need Tomcat to be installed in order to launch my java based server (socket server)?
If yes Which version do I need, and can you please give me a reference for an online guide for how to install and run things on a VPS which is based on Linux.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. If your are not deploying web apps (WAR's), you don't need a application server like tomcat or glassfish. So to run your java  based server, you only need the JRE.
2. Get a Windows-based VPS if you are not familiar with Linux, as you have to administrate the server (apply patches, etc.), if it is not managed by your provider.
3. Have a look at this [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/21416/book-for-linux-newbies) for Linux books.